# Grep multiple strings and know which string was located and where

Tags: regex, string, bash, grep

I have some log files which I need to grep and cut from.
I am looking for a few different strings in the log files with this code below which is fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
STR="string1\|string2\|string3\|string4"
grep -E -i ${STR} 144.gnmap | cut -d" " -f2 >> 144.lst

1. 111.111.111.111 - logdata random text blah blah blah blah blah string1 blah 
2. 222.222.222.222 = logdata random text blah string3 blah blah blah blah blah 
3. 111.111.111.123 + logdata random text string4 blah blah blah blah blah 
4. 111.111.222.111 ) logdata logdata random text blah blah blah blah blah string1 blah 
5. 222.222.222.101 0 logdata random text blah blah blah string1 blah 
6. 222.123.222.123 - logdata which contains string3 somewhere in the string
```

** Just to clarify, the string1, string4 etc in the text file is randomly located so I don't know where it will be located. The string can also occur multiple times.

What I want to do is correlate the IP in the log to the grep'd "string" that was found.

Is there someway to know which string is being grep'd and correlate it against the IP like this. Can it be done with grep or does it need another method, if so, some options please.

```
1. 111.111.111.111 string1 
2. 222.222.222.222 string3 
3. 111.111.111.123 string4 
4. 111.111.222.111 string1 
5. 222.222.222.101 string1 
6. 222.123.222.123 string3
```

*Edit : updated for further clarification.

as an example, the grep could be something like

```
1. 111.111.111.111 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt) 
2. 222.222.222.222 Mozilla/4.75 [en](X11;U;Linux2.2.16-22 i586)
```

where I might be searching for Windows and Linux as an example and I want to relate it to the IP.

Comment: Is the text at the bottom of the first code block a sample of your log file? Are you searching for literal strings, as opposed to regular expressions?

Comment: If you have more detail to add, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with awk:

```
s='string1|string2|string3'
awk -vPAT="$s" 'match($0,PAT){print $2,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file1 file2...
```

Here I'm assuming that the ip field is the second field (`$2`) where fields are whitespace-separated. I'm also assuming that you want to construct the regex independently of the `awk` invocation; otherwise it would have just been:

```
awk 'match($0,/string1|string2|string3/){print $2,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file1 file2...
```

I'm using an explicit call to `match` in order to set `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, so that I can print out the actual string matched.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty ugly but works

```
s="string1|string2|string3"
grep -E $s logfile| sed -re "s/^([0-9]+\.)\s*([0-9.]+)\s+.*($s).*/\1 \2 \3/g"
```

The sed bit means "match (1.) (111.222.333.444) some stuff (string)1 some other stuff" and replace it with "1. 111.222.333.444 string1"